# Rxjava how to create a thread and return text to UI

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I want run a new thread, when user click on the button. In this thread i call Sleep(2000) after "i++" and return string ("Text" + i) in TextView.
I have example but it don't work:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Void> subscriber) {
        SystemClock.sleep(2000); 
        i++;

        subscriber.onNext(null);

        subscriber.onCompleted(); 
    }
})
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) 
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(new Action1<Void>() { 
            @Override
            public void call(Void aVoid) {
                // code like text.setText("text" + i)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use RxJava1 or RxJava2/3?

Do you want to create a new Thread on very subscription? If yes, when you would use `Schedulers.newThread()` instead of `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())`

In RxJava2/3 it is not allowed to emit null `subscriber.onNext(null);`. This is actually your issue. You want to emit i++ and not `null`.

I would rather do something like this:

```
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
      
      Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        return i.incrementAndGet();
      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(....)
        .subscribe(v -> ...)
```

It is not recommended to mutate state from different threads without any synchronization, therefore use AtomicInteger.